# How to read multiple queues messages from rabbitmq to logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash

I have 3 different queues in rabbitmq where I have to read messages and send  them to elasticsearch in the same index. I am confuse it is possible to read multiple queues in single config file. I am already reading one queue at a time. But I am getting realtime messages from different queues and need to process at the same time all these three queues?

Answer (score 1):

you can, you need one input section for each queue